# ASP.NET AJAX not sending over data, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, razor-pages

What I am doing here is I am a displaying a dynamic table. Once I click on the button, all I want to do is just receive anything in the updated fields. CI am getting a null reference exception when I try to loop over them in the foreach loop in the OnPostUpdateAttendance. Currently, there 3 fields that can be updated. I know the problem is when I am either capturing the data or when I am sending it over, which is in the HTML or script.

```
// The HTML

<h2>Attendance Records:</h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Uid</th>
                        <th>Student Name</th>
                        <th>Attendance Status</th>
                        <th>Minutes Late</th>
                        <th>Absence Reason</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var att in Model.Attendance)
                    {
                        <tr data-uid="@att.uid" data-classid="@Model.SelectedClassId">
                            <td>@att.uid</td>
                            <td>@att.student_Name</td>
                            <td>
                                <select asp-for="@att.student_Status">
                                    @foreach (var statusOption in Model.Ref_ClassStudentStatusType)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@statusOption.Status_Type_ID">@statusOption.Status_Type_Name</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input asp-for="@att.Minutes_Late" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input asp-for="@att.Absence_Reason" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="separator-row">
                            <td colspan="5"><!-- Empty cell to create the separation --></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="SelectedClassId" value="@Model.SelectedClassId" />
                <input type="hidden" name="SelectedDate" value="@Model.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
                <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="UpdateAttendance">Update Attendance</button>
               @* <span id="loading" style="display:none;"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>*@
            </form>

//The script
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#updateAttendanceButton').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

                var updatedAttendance = [];

                // Loop through the table rows and gather data
                $('table tbody tr').each(function () {
                    var uid = $(this).data('uid');
                    var classId = $(this).data('classid');
                    var studentStatus = $(this).find('select').val();
                    var minutesLate = $(this).find('input[name="att.Minutes_Late"]').val();
                    var absenceReason = $(this).find('input[name="att.Absence_Reason"]').val();

                    updatedAttendance.push({
                        uid: uid,
                        classId: classId,
                        student_Status: studentStatus,
                        Minutes_Late: minutesLate,
                        Absence_Reason: absenceReason
                    });
                });

                // Send the data to the server using AJAX
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '?handler=UpdateAttendance',
                    data: JSON.stringify(updatedAttendance),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        // Handle the response if needed
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}


// Model
 public IActionResult OnPostUpdateAttendance([FromBody] List<UpdatedAttendanceModel> updatedAttendance)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Received data: ");
            try
            {
                foreach (var attendance in updatedAttendance)
                {
                    var uid = attendance.uid;
                    var classId = attendance.Class_ID;
                    var studentStatus = attendance.student_Status;
                    var minutesLate = attendance.Minutes_Late;
                    var absenceReason = attendance.Absence_Reason;

                    // Process the updated attendance data here...
                }

                // Return a response indicating success
                return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle errors if needed
                return new JsonResult(new { success = false, errorMessage = ex.Message });
            }
        }
    
//update model. 
 public class UpdatedAttendanceModel
    {
        public int? uid { get; set; }

        public string? Class_ID { get; set; }

        public DateTime? attendance_date { get; set; }

        public string? student_Status { get; set; }

        public string? student_Name { get; set; }

        public int? Minutes_Late { get; set; }
        public string? Absence_Reason { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Try `console.log` of the `updatedAttendance` array before you make the POST and see if it has data in it. Also, try removing the `JSON.stringify` and just pass the object and see if that works

Comment: This is a good time to start familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  Are there any errors on the browser console?  On the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What data does it contain?  How does that data differ from what you expect?  When using the script debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: @zgood Thank you, let me try removing the JSon.stringify. also, the problem is now how I am collecting the data, it is how I am sending it. I added a var test = "test" and tried printing it server side, it was empty.

Comment: @David So, I did console.log after introducing a new local variable and it does print to console, how ever I get an error 400 after that . the error is not allowing the request to reach the server.

Comment: @zgood did test data variable and shows in console.log client side. I am getting bad request on client side

Comment: @AliSoujod: If the server is responding with an HTTP 400 error code then the request is reaching the server, because the server is producing a response.  The server wouldn't send a response if it never received a request.  When you examine that request in your browser's debugging tools (on the network tab), does it include the data you expect?  If not, how does the data differ from what you expect?  In the body of the response, is there any additional information about why the error was produced?

Comment: @David I am not getting anything else other than this "http://localhost:5069/Privacy?handler=UpdateAttendance 400 (Bad Request)". It is printing out to console log the data I have told it to from the client side, how ever I also have a print to console debug server side which is what it is not doing.

Comment: @AliSoujod: It sounds like you're not checking the Network tab in the browser's debugging tools.  If you want to observe additional information about network requests and responses, that is where you would do that.

Comment: @David I had to take a different route. I had an a senior check the code and everything was right. Also, I am looking in the network tab. It could have been the workplace limitations that are put by the admins, will see tomorrow, but generally everything is correct and coded right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have failed to include the Request Verification Token in your AJAX Post request so the framework returns a 400 Bad Request status code: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors

Unless there is a compelling reason to post the data as JSON, the simplest solution is to serialise the form content and post that. The `<form>` tag helper automatically generates a hidden field containing the request token so all you need to do is this:

```
$.post(`?handler=updateattendance`, $('form').serialize(), function(){...});
```

Remove the `FromBody` attribute from the handler parameters.

Otherwise you need to include the value of the hidden field in the AJAX request headers:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "?handler=updateattendance",
    data: { foo: "bar" },
    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
    success: function (response) {
```

Comment: YESS! Thank you, it works. I had to take a different route yesterday, but after trying it this way it works.